# logistic regression global maximum

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am uncertain if this is the case both in general *(does logistic regression always find global optimum)*

and in particular *(does logistic regression always find global optimum when that the optimisation converges)*

I also posted in stackoverflow but found out the post fits better in math.stackexchange. You may see the original [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785395/does-logistic-regression-always-find-global-optimum-assuming-that-the-optimisat)

Comment: formulas please: what optimization problem are you solving? Is it convex?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually it is a general question given by my professor, so this is all information we are given.